# How to configure tinymce to remove extra spaces in Django?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

Recently I started using `tinymce` in my project and after posting I am getting extra white space between paragraphs.

[image]

If I use `ctrl+enter` that helps a bit. 
I tried `p{margin:0; padding:0;}` that didn't helped as well. I searched documentation, but I couldn't find anything concerning this, maybe I couldn't find it. 
There must be something in configuration of tinymce in `settings.py`, I hope you help me. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly tied to your CSS.  When you init TinyMCE it has a Theme and Skin that provide a default set of CSS.   Browsers do the same thing - if you open an HTML page and don't provide any CSS the browser has defaults for how it renders HTML.

If you want to change how things render you need to pass CSS into TinyMCE (via the `content_css` configuration setting) to change how the editor renders HTML.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css

I would note that the font in your screenshot is not the default for TinyMCE so I suspect that there is indeed some CSS being passed into TinyMCE already and that its spacing for lists is likely not what you are expecting.

I would look at the CSS you are passing to TinyMCE and adjust it as needed to get the spacing you require.

***Note:***  *Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in TinyMCE creates a new paragraph (`<p>`).  Pressing  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a line break (`<br>`).  These would typically have different line spacing, margin, and padding and could lead to different spacing outcomes.*